# How to integrate openNI in Qt in Ubuntu?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, kinect, openni

Currently I am making a project on recognizing human actions using Kinect. Since I work in Ubuntu and I need the skeleton information, I choose openNI and NITE. I want to use Qt to create a GUI application, but I don't know how to integrate openNI in Qt. All the samples of openNI and NITE run well, but I failed to build any of them in Qt creator. I really hope anyone can help me on this(Say how to build NiUserTracker in Qt creator). I will also apriciate it if anyone can give some sample Qt projects.

I have tried to build NiUserTracker in Qt creator:
Content of .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt
INCLUDEPATH += /home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Include

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    SceneDrawer.cpp \
    opengles.cpp

HEADERS += \
    SceneDrawer.h \
    opengles.h

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib/release/ -lnimCodecs
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib/debug/ -lnimCodecs
else:symbian: LIBS += -lnimCodecs
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib/ -lnimCodecs

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib/release/ -lnimMockNodes
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib/debug/ -lnimMockNodes
else:symbian: LIBS += -lnimMockNodes
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib/ -lnimMockNodes

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib/release/ -lnimRecorder
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib/debug/ -lnimRecorder
else:symbian: LIBS += -lnimRecorder
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib/ -lnimRecorder

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib/release/ -lOpenNI
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib/debug/ -lOpenNI
else:symbian: LIBS += -lOpenNI
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib/ -lOpenNI

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib/release/ -lOpenNI
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib/debug/ -lOpenNI
else:symbian: LIBS += -lOpenNI
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib/ -lOpenNI

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../../../../home/myname/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.4.0/Lib
```

I have added the inlcude path of openNI and libs, however when I built the program, it shows:

```
SceneDrawer.o: In function `initTexture(void**, int&, int&)':
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `glGenTextures'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to `glBindTexture'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri'
SceneDrawer.o: In function `DrawRectangle(float, float, float, float)':
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x144): undefined reference to `glVertexPointer'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x160): undefined reference to `glDrawArrays'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x165): undefined reference to `glFlush'
SceneDrawer.o: In function `DrawTexture(float, float, float, float)':
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x19b): undefined reference to `glEnableClientState'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x1bf): undefined reference to `glTexCoordPointer'
SceneDrawer.o: In function `glPrintString(void*, char*)':
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x22f): undefined reference to `glutBitmapCharacter'
SceneDrawer.o: In function `DrawLimb(unsigned int, XnSkeletonJoint, XnSkeletonJoint)':
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x24c): undefined reference to `g_UserGenerator'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x306): undefined reference to `g_UserGenerator'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x3da): undefined reference to `g_UserGenerator'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x488): undefined reference to `g_UserGenerator'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x5ab): undefined reference to `g_DepthGenerator'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x5ef): undefined reference to `glVertex3i'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x62b): undefined reference to `glVertex3i'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x65a): undefined reference to `g_UserGenerator'
SceneDrawer.o: In function `drawCircle(float, float, float)':
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x7e0): undefined reference to `glBegin'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x841): undefined reference to `glVertex2f'
SceneDrawer.o: In function `DrawJoint(unsigned int, XnSkeletonJoint)':
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x869): undefined reference to `g_UserGenerator'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x91d): undefined reference to `g_UserGenerator'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x9d2): undefined reference to `g_UserGenerator'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0xabf): undefined reference to `g_DepthGenerator'
SceneDrawer.o: In function `DrawDepthMap(xn::DepthMetaData const&, xn::SceneMetaData const&)':
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0xdb7): undefined reference to `g_bDrawPixels'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0xf0c): undefined reference to `g_bDrawBackground'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0xf85): undefined reference to `glBindTexture'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0xfd4): undefined reference to `glTexImage2D'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0xff8): undefined reference to `glColor4f'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x1004): undefined reference to `glEnable'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x1052): undefined reference to `glDisable'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x108f): undefined reference to `g_UserGenerator'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x10d1): undefined reference to `g_bDrawSkeleton'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x10f4): undefined reference to `g_bPrintID'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x1107): undefined reference to `g_UserGenerator'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x1114): undefined reference to `g_DepthGenerator'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x115b): undefined reference to `g_bPrintState'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x11d6): undefined reference to `glColor4f'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x1210): undefined reference to `glRasterPos2i'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x121b): undefined reference to `glutBitmapHelvetica18'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x1225): undefined reference to `g_bDrawSkeleton'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x1233): undefined reference to `g_UserGenerator'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x1348): undefined reference to `glColor4f'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x134e): undefined reference to `g_bMarkJoints'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x1362): undefined reference to `glBegin'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x154b): undefined reference to `glEnd'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x155a): undefined reference to `g_UserGenerator'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x187a): undefined reference to `g_UserGenerator'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x1b02): undefined reference to `g_bPrintFrameID'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x1b87): undefined reference to `glColor4f'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x1b9b): undefined reference to `glRasterPos2i'
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x1baa): undefined reference to `glutBitmapHelvetica18'
SceneDrawer.o: In function `DrawTexture(float, float, float, float)':
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x1f3): undefined reference to `glDisableClientState'
SceneDrawer.o: In function `drawCircle(float, float, float)':
SceneDrawer.cpp:(.text+0x854): undefined reference to `glEnd'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I guess it is because the glut libs are not included. However both libs are .lib files, which seems cannot be added in Qt creator....

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you don't show any details of what "fails to build" actually means, how do you expect anyone to help you fix those? Please describe exactly what you did to try and integrate them, and the exact error messages you're seeing.

Comment: @Mat:I've updated my question, please have a look.

Comment: You're adding a bunch of libraries already in your .pro file. Why aren't you adding the OpenGL ones too, in the same fashion?

Comment: Do you mean glut32.lib and glut64.lib? It seems they cannot be added in Qt creator in the same fashion..  It seems becasue they are not .so files..

Comment: @Mat:Do you mean glut32.lib and glut64.lib? It seems they cannot be added in Qt creator in the same fashion.. It seems becasue they are not .so files..

Comment: Why does that "seem" to be the case? What happens when you try? What error message? (And I doubt you should try to include both a *32.lib and a *64.lib file to the same build)

Comment: @Mat: Have you ever tried to add .lib files to your project in Qt creator? I tried it by right clicking on the project name and choosing "add libs". There's no "error message" because you just cannot find any .lib files in the opened dialogue. Then how could you add them into your project? I can add .so files in the same fashion because the .so files simply show up in the opened dialogue.  Well, if you have ever used Qt creator before, you should know this way. It's really not that complex and I really don't know how to express it more clearly...

Comment: Anyway, I have solved this problem by adding my openGL lib path..They're .so files located in other folders. The .lib files provided by the sample have no use in linux.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to use openNI with openCV + qt support? 
another soluction is this.

http://develnoter.blogspot.com.br/2012/05/integrating-opencv-in-qt-gui.html

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged (links tend to get stale over time).
Please consider editing your answer and adding a synopsis here.